# MySQL select datetime records with 30 minute interval in a datetime column

Tags: mysql

I was hoping someone could help me with a query? I have a table with entries/rows written every 10 seconds 24/7 so a lot of rows and for graphing it takes eons. I want to select one row every 30 minutes, an example is probably best. The following works, but gives me every result at those 30 minute intervals.

```
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE mytimestamp AND mod(minute(time),30) = 0
```

Gives me results where time is like this

```
2014-03-01 01:30:01
2014-03-01 01:30:13
2014-03-01 01:30:24
2014-03-01 01:30:35
2014-03-01 01:30:46
2014-03-01 01:30:58
2014-03-01 02:00:01
2014-03-01 02:00:13
2014-03-01 02:00:24
2014-03-01 02:00:35
2014-03-01 02:00:46
2014-03-01 02:00:57
```

What I would like is just one result like this

```
2014-03-01 01:30:01
2014-03-01 02:00:01
2014-03-01 02:30:01
```

Comment: Do you want record within 30 mins or ever 30mis?

Comment: @RajavelD Every 30 mins interval per record

Comment: why not just add LIMIT 1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example and the posted answer you want, you want intervals ending in :30:01 or :00:01 correct?

one method you can use is LIKE

```
select * from SamplerTable where
(Daytime like '%:00:01%') or (Daytime like '%:30:01%');
```

Although, take note that records inserted MUST absolutely end with :30:01 or :00:01 with this method.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd9e2/5) here. Let me know if this helped.

EDIT:Closest to 00 or 30, perhaps like will still work.

```
 select * from SamplerTable where
    (Daytime like '%:00:%') or (Daytime like '%:30:%');
```

will output records with minutes 00 or 30. You can just add order by to sort the output asc or desc

EDIT: Like still works, just add GROUP by:

```
select * from SamplerTable where
(Daytime like '%:00:%') or (Daytime like '%:30:%')
group by DATE_FORMAT(Daytime, '%Y-%M-%d %H:%i')
```

CREDIT goes to Rajavel D forthis answer. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d35d63/1)

Comment: almost, except they aren't always 01 they might be 02,3 etc , I only need one though or the closest to :00

Comment: check my edits, or try this : select * from SamplerTable where
    (Daytime like '%:00:%') or (Daytime like '%:30:%');

Comment: Doesn't work, still selects multiple rows @ :00 or :30

EDIT: Using '%:00:0%' '%:30:0%' seems to be holding up for now

Comment: Perhaps access said records with a front-end language like php or vb.net, then loop through all of it?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM db.table
WHERE 
    (mytimestamp like '%:00:%') or (mytimestamp like '%:30:%')
GROUP BY group by DATE_FORMAT(mytimestamp, '%Y-%M-%d %H:%i')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6779a4/11

Comment: rats! forgot about GROUP by! +1

Comment: can you produce a sample fiddle sir?